# Convert array of timestamps with Date javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, foreach, timestamp

I have an array of timestamps and I want to transform it into dates.

```
timestamps = [1568666854141, 1568595225048, 1568594645595];
timestamps.forEach(function(d) { d = new Date(d) } )
```

When I do `new Date(d)` in debug it gives me `Mon Sep 16 2019 16:47:34 GMT-0400` which is good, but if I check my array, it's still the same. It gives me
`[1568666854141, 1568595225048, 1568594645595]` instead of `[Mon Sep 16 2019 16:47:34 GMT-0400, ...]`
 Why does not every element `d` reassigns to a date?

Comment: you're just reassigning the variable d, it has no affect on the original array, you should do it like so `timestamps.forEach(function(d, i) { timestamps[i] = new Date(d) } )`

Answer (score 3):

forEach can not modify the orgin array, please use map:

```js
let timestamps = [1568666854141, 1568595225048, 1568594645595];
timestamps = timestamps.map(function(d) { return new Date(d) } )
```

Comment: *map* doesn't modify the original array either. ;-) *forEach* can be used, though *map* is more semantic.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new array and creating a new (correct) date value for each element, but not doing anything with the values.

- Return the values rather than just creating them;
- Assign the new array back to the same name;
- Create a new array (instead of just iterating over the `timestamps` array) by [using `map` instead of `forEach` [link to good explanation of the difference]](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f)

```js
timestamps = timestamps.map(function(d) { return new Date(d) } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem doing this:

`timestamps.forEach(function(elem, idx, arr) {arr[idx] = new Date(elem); });`

Comment: You should use `map` for this instead (see my answer as well as the other answer); especially if you don't need access to that array for all of the other values.

Comment: `map` and `forEach` otherwise behave very similarly; but this is an important case where you can really benefit from the fact that `map` returns an array _for you_. (Check out the link in my answer below for more details on this specifically.)